# Script for replacing color codes to color names?

Tags: c#, html, colors, batch-file

Does anyone know a way to change color codes to color names? I have an XML with color codes:
I need: `#FFFFFF` to replace to `White` and `#000000` to `Black` etc.

If you know a script, batch, C# program or anyway to this it ill be greatly appreciated

Thanks  :)

Comment: Why would you want to? Can you offer some context here?

Comment: I think you'll have to create the script yourself, this table might help - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colorvalues.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method which will retrieve the name or the RGB value if none is found:

```
static Color[] colors = typeof(Color)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(pi => pi.CanRead && pi.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
    .Select(pi => (Color)pi.GetValue(null, null))
    .ToArray();

static IEnumerable<string> FindColorNames(string htmlColor)
{
    // like "#RRGGBB" or "#AARRGGBB" or "Red" or "red"
    var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(htmlColor);
    return colors.Where(cc => cc.R == color.R
                           && cc.G == color.G
                           && cc.B == color.B
                           && cc.A == color.A)
                 .Select(cc => cc.Name);
}

static string FindColorName(string htmlColor)
{
    return FindColorNames(htmlColor).FirstOrDefault() ?? htmlColor;
}

// #FFFFFF: White
// #000000: Black
// #333333: 333333
// #FF00FF: Fuchsia (Magenta also matches)
```

An update which uses a nicer search mode:

```
static Dictionary<int, string[]> colors = static Color[] colors = typeof(Color)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(pi => pi.CanRead && pi.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
    .Select(pi => (Color)pi.GetValue(null, null))
    .GroupBy(cc => cc.ToArgb())
    .ToDictionary(gg => gg.Key, gg.Select(cc => cc.Name).ToArray());

static IEnumerable<string> FindColorNames(string htmlColor)
{
    var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(htmlColor);
    string[] names;
    if (!colors.TryGetValue(color.ToArgb(), out names))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    return names;
}

static string FindColorName(string htmlColor)
{
    return FindColorNames.FirstOrDefault() ?? htmlColor;
}
```

Comment: @JeremyThompson: switched to `ColorTranslator` to do the conversion per your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This kinda sucks, and may give slightly unexpected values, but is technically correct. Feel free to update with your own color name list:

```
    public string GetColorName(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        return GetColorName(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
    }

    public string GetColorName(Color color)
    {
        foreach (var knownColorName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(KnownColor)))
        {
            var knownColor = Color.FromName(knownColorName);
            if (knownColor.R == color.R && knownColor.G == color.G && knownColor.B == color.B)
            {
                return knownColorName;
            }
        }
        return color.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF")


Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command-line tool that does exactly what you want: [Cict](https://github.com/kallaballa/Cict)

Example:

```
$ ./cict 000001
1   #000000 black

$ ./cict FFFFFF
0   #FFFFFF white
```

As you can see, you simple pass a 24-bit hex-value to cict and it reports the distance to the color found, the value of the actual color and the name.

(I am the author of Cict)